# How to get the particular value from the JSON file using the HASH MAP in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a JSON file

```
{
  "msg": "ACTIVITY DATA found",
  "data": {
    "USTUDENT8": 0,
    "USTUDENT7": 0,
    "USTUDENT6": 0,
    "USTUDENT5": 0,
    "USTUDENT4": 0,
    "USTUDENT3": 0,
    "USTUDENT2": 0,
    "UTEACHER": 0,
    "EVERYONE": 2
  }
}
```

From this I need to get the value of EVERYONE particularly.

```
@Override
public void response(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {

    List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONArray arrayObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayObject.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject dataObject = arrayObject.getJSONObject(i);
        message = dataObject.getString("EVERYONE");
        allNames.add(message);
        Log.d("Message", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: your json response in data is jsonobject not jsonarray.

Comment: you get data from "data" is json object not it is json array you  must change in to json array

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@Override
public void response(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {

    List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
            message = data.getString("EVERYONE");
            allNames.add(message);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine

Comment: welcome,  please accept my answer.

Comment: Can you explain the same if it is an array object how will I get it applicable?

Comment: sure , can you please send that JSON where you get array of objects

Comment: {
  "msg": "ACTIVITY DATA found",
  "data": [
    {
      "publish": true,
      "sentOn": 1496120119380,
      "recipient": "EVERYONE",
      "taggedTo": "",
      "sender": {
        "id": "UTEACHER"
      },
      "text": "hi all"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: From this I need to get each and every values separately like sender,taggedTo,text etc.,

Comment: JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject iObj=data.getJSONObject(i);
                publish=iObj.getBoolean("publish");
                sentOn=iObj.getLong("sentOn");
                recipient=iObj.getString("recipient");
                taggedTo=iObj.getString("taggedTo");
                sender=iObj.getJSONObject("sender");
                id=sender.getString("id");
            }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145513/discussion-between-pratik-vyas-and-mahalakshmi-saravanan).

Comment: Thanks a lot working fine

Comment: welcome,please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

```
JSONObject arrayObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
message = arrayObject.getString("EVERYONE");
allNames.add(message);
Log.d("Message", message);
```

Comment: `jsonObject.getJSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You are trying to get 'data' `JSONObject` using `jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")`, Which is totally wrong. Use `jsonObject.getJSONObject("data")` to get the 'data' `JSONObject`.

**2.** As the value of `EVERYONE` is an `integer` value, use `dataObject.getInt("EVERYONE")` instead of `dataObject.getString("EVERYONE")` to get the value of `EVERYONE`.

**Update your code as below:**

```
    .........
    ................

    List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

        int everyone = dataObject.getInt("EVERYONE");

        Log.d("SUCCESS", "EVERYONE: " + everyone);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    .......
    ...................
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
D/SUCCESS: EVERYONE: 2
```

Hope this helps~